# C++ Polymorphism with types

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I am trying to have a Node which has a variable with type T, `T data;` along with storing pointers to its parent node `NodeBase *parent;`.

The classes look as such:

```
class Node: public NodeBase {
    T data;
    NodeBase *parent;
public:
    Node(T);
    void setData(T);
    T * getData(void);
    void setParent(NodeBase * const);
    NodeBase * getParent(void);
};

class NodeBase {
};
```

I thought that I could put a pure virtual function in `NodeBase`, but you have to specify the return type, and since `NodeBase` does not have a type I cannot specify `virtual T * getData(void) = 0;`

The specific case that I am having issues with:

```
Node<char> n1 = Node('A');
Node<int>  n2 = Node(63);
n1.setParent(&n2);

NodeBase *pNode = n1.getParent();
pNode->getData(); // Error: BaseNode has no member 'getData()'
```

Comment: getData would have to be a virtual memeber function of nodebase - and more importantly it would have to have a known type, so that evey call to `NodeBase* p; p->getData();` would return the same type

Comment: Can you make `NodeBase` a template class?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of `NodeBase`? Will you have multiple implementations of it?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ie curiously recurring template pattern? that's a good/idiomatic solution, but OP needs to understand that two Nodes of different type can't be treated as having the same base type.

Comment: @user3125280 OIC...the OP wants a common base class for both `Node<char>` and `Node<int>`.

Comment: @user3125280 I had something simpler in mind that CRTP.

Comment: If you need a node that can hold multiple types, look into using std::variant instead of T as the type

Comment: @Code-Apprentice if I did that then I would not be able to have a `Node` that has a `NodeBase *parent` of a different type. This is of course with my limited knowledge, but if there is a way using this, please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a templated function to `NodeBase`:

```
class NodeBase {
    public:
       template<typename T>
       T* getData();
};
```

Which would cast the object into `Node<T>` and return `getData()`. Here's a working example - included only cause it actually took me a while to fix problems with cyclic definitions:

```
class NodeBase {
    public:
    template<typename T>
    T* getData();
};

template<typename T>
class Node: public NodeBase {
    T data;
    NodeBase *parent;

protected:  
    friend NodeBase;
    T * getData(void){return &data;};

public:
    Node(T var){data=var;};
    void setData(T& var){data=var;};
    void setParent(NodeBase * const par){parent=par;};
    NodeBase * getParent(void){return parent;};
};

template<typename T>
T* NodeBase::getData(){ return dynamic_cast<Node<T>*>(this)->getData();};


int main(){
    Node<char> n1 = Node<char>('A');
    Node<int>  n2 = Node<int>(63);
    n1.setParent(&n2);

    NodeBase *pNode = n1.getParent();
    std::cout << *pNode->getData<int>() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but if OP knew data pNode's type at call site, all he would of needed is a cast... this is not type safe except in the trivial case. what does this code do that a cast doesn't?

Comment: @user3125280 it hides the logic in a class and __requires__ (not only _lets_, but _requires_) the user to actually say what type he needs. From my knowledge - it's as type safe as a cast, so its peculiar you're mentioning both things in one comment. Could you elaborate? I see your answer below, but I can't see why `typeid` couldn't be applied here, making it as safe?

Comment: Polymorphism means that code can be written agnostic to the underlying type of the object - either by querying the type (`typeid`) or ignoring it (`virtual`). for example OP want's to be able to recover the data stored in the underlying type - but can't always know it's type. does your answer address this? how would you write a function that got passed an arbitrary `NodeBase*`? [see an example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7eb3f3a4e2c0f953) `typeid` isn't (IMHO) part of the solution, to be tacked on afterwards "for safety". it is the solution. this is why it exists.

Comment: also reinterpret cast is [plain wrong here](https://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/RZ/software/SUNWspro/c-plusplus/c%2B%2B_ug/Cast.new.doc.html) "reinterpret_cast cannot be used to convert between pointers to two different classes that are related by inheritance" - easily fixed though

Comment: @user3125280 "for example OP want's to be able to recover the data stored in the underlying type - but can't always know it's type. does your answer address this?" I think the OP knows best what he needs. Since this is the accepted answer now, I guess this is what he needed. You're right about the `reinterpret_cast` tho. Gonna change it ASAP.

Comment: By the way - why would anyone pass a `NodeBase` there? I guess the OP wants to create a container linking elements of many types. For the love of my life - can't think of a place when inserting an abstract node would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are confusing run-time polymorphism with compile-time polymorphism. Templates provide the later. One possible solution to your problem is to make `NodeBase` a template class:

```
template <class T>
class NodeBase {
    public:
        virtual T getData() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Node : NodeBase<T> {
    T data;
    NodeBase *parent;

public:
    Node(T);
    void setData(T);
    T getData(void);
    void setParent(NodeBase<T> * const);
    NodeBase<T> * getParent(void);
};
```

Note that I made `getData` return `T` rather than `T*`. (Is there a reason to return a pointer?)

Comment: The issue with this is `Node` cannot have `NodeBase *parent` where the parent is of a different type than the specific `Node`. For instance, `Node<int>` could not have a parent of `Node<char>`.

Comment: @MichaelMitchell Exactly. I don't think there is a way to do what you want because the signature of `getData()` depends on the argument to your template class.

Comment: @MichaelMitchell So are you saying that you want to store both `char`s and `int`s in the same list? Can you provide a use-case for this?

Comment: No, those were just random cases, I need a solution that works for many types.

Comment: @MichaelMitchell Can you provide a concrete example? For instance, by "many types", do you mean "many **built-in** types" or "many **user-defined** types"? (For the later, you can create an inheritance hierarchy.)

Comment: Unfortunately, both :/

Answer (score 2):

C++ is statically typed, so everytime you write code like this:

```
NodeBase *pNode = n1.getParent();
pNode->getData(); // Error: BaseNode has no member 'getData()'
```

the compiler needs to know the type of `getData()`. In your case, you want it to be either `int(void)` or `char(void)` - functions with no arguments returning `char` or `int`.

There are ways around this. The strategy will depend on your situation. There are a few cases for the return type:

- A fixed set of bultins - use a union
- A fix set of builtins or classes, but the type will never be changed - use a union
- A fix set of builtins or classes, but the type may change - use boost variant
- Any other case - use boost any

So in summary, add a virtual function to the base class (non-templated) that returns one of the above data structures. The documentation for boost is easy to find online.

The reason why this is so much more difficult in c++ is because other languages (especially dynamic languages) hide the difficulty. When a function call is made, space is allocated - typically on the stack for the best speed - and the return value is copied into that space. If you want to return an unknown type you need to either make the maximum space available of all possible return types (a union, maybe boost variant?) or allocate that space from the heap (boost any). Many statically typed languages provide good support only for the former.

C++ does have some helpful features if you want to do it yourself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

struct NodeBase {
    virtual ~NodeBase(){}
};

template<typename T>
struct Node: public NodeBase {
    T data;
    NodeBase *parent;

    Node(T data, NodeBase* parent = nullptr)
        : data(data), parent(parent)
    {}

    ~Node(){}
};

int main()
{
    Node<int>  n2(63);
    Node<char> n1('A', &n2);

    NodeBase* b = n1.parent; //pointer to n2

    if(typeid(*b) == typeid(Node<int>))
        cout << ((Node<int>*) b)->data << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that typeinfo and at least one virtual function in NodeBase are required for this to work.

Comment: I am more interested in learning how to rather than using a library, but now I have a place to look, thank you.

Comment: @MichaelMitchell in that case, ill add an example with the `typeid` operator

Answer (score -1):

```
NodeBase *pNode = n1.getParent();
pNode->getData(); // Error: BaseNode has no member 'getData()'
```

You have pNode (child), so you can use directly to `getData()`, secondly your base class know nothing about  `getData()`, so using upcasted pointer you cannot call it.